# R - ggplot2 in Shiny - How to extract/get/set current x/y/both axis range from a previous plot/graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am using the Shiny package. 
I have a ggplot2 graph and its bounds are updated automatically whenever the user changes the input.  I have a control that says "Fix current axis range".

**I want the control to determine the current x and/or y ranges of the previous Shiny graph and use it as input for the new one about to be created.**

I planned to use a function like coord_cartesian to fix the desired bound.

Another option is simply having a function with the option of fixing the x, y, or both bounds but I had no luck finding one.

How can this be done ?

-------------**update**---------------

Failed attempt with a global variable because coord_cartesian doesn't return what I expected. What does it return (I couldn't find documentation) ?

```
#---------------SNIPPET---------------
#global variable
yaxis

#renderPlot 
if(input$yaxis == "default") {
    y <- coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1, 1))
    yaxis <- y
}
else if(input$yaxis == "variable") {

    yaxis <- ggplot_build(q)$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range
}
else if(input$yaxis == "fixed") {
    y <- yaxis
}

print(q + y)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by previous graph . Is this done in Shiny?

Comment: Yes it is done in Shiny. The default setting adjusts the bounds automatically to fit the data on the screen.

Comment: I want to give the user the ability to 'lock' the bounds.

Comment: Use this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/zajV1HsstYc/fi7GfwsNWpgJ to get the current session then use redis or some other lightweight cache (heck, even sqlite3) to store the data you need to reference there and yank it back when re-doing it. It's per-session, so when the session closes it'll be gone.

Comment: That's an old message, the more recent solution uses the session parameter. However, it is explicitly not meant for storing user variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Joe Cheng, I re-read the scoping chapter and noted that I had always gotten it wrong before. Here is the simpler version; I deleted my old one to avoid confusion, sorry for the blunder.

### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  maxx = 1
  maxy = 1
  output$simpleplot <- renderPlot({
    input$nextButton # create dependency on action button
    scalex = round(runif(1,0.1,1),2)
    scaley = round(runif(1,0.1,1),2)
    fix = isolate(input$fixscale)
    
    if (fix){
      plot(runif(100,0,scalex),runif(100,0,scaley),pch=16,cex=0.5,
           xlim= c(0,maxx), ylim=c(0,maxy))
      
    } else {
      maxx <<- scalex
      maxy <<- scaley
      updateNumericInput(session,"maxx", value=scalex)
      updateNumericInput(session,"maxy", value=scaley)
      plot(runif(100,0,scalex),runif(100,0,scaley),pch=16,cex=0.5,
           col="red")    
    }  
  })
})
```

### ui.r

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("FixScale Test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxInput("fixscale", "Fix Scale", FALSE),
    actionButton("nextButton", "Next"),
    br()
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("simpleplot")
  )
))
```

Comment: Looks great! 
To take the workaround 1 step further how would we hide 'maxx' and 'maxy'? I tried adding this (borrowed) in ui.r: tags$head(tags$script(HTML('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsCode",
function(message) {console.log(message)eval(message.code);});')))

Comment: and this in server.r:   session$sendCustomMessage(type="jsCode",list(code= paste("$('#",maxx,"').hide()",sep="")))

Comment: I haven't looked closely at this but to hide anything in ui.R you can wrap it in `tags$div(style="display:none", ...)`. If you do this to outputs they'll stop calculating automatically by default, but inputs should be unaffected.

Comment: Thanks, Joe, I had read that chapter half a dozen of times and only realized it's content now.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind that the current scale is global, i.e. forced on all active users, you can assign the current sizes to  global variable, for example in `global.R` with `<<-`.

However, you probably want a per-user setting which requires authentication. This is not yet possible, but check [Jeff Allens comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/6arkSlzPdLo/40cRsINBjHcJ) on the shiny forum:

Comment: Thanks, I guess I thought there would be a built-in mechanism to do stuff like this.

Comment: If you want it per-session (which I think is actually what you want, not per-user) then just declare the value inside of `shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { ... })` and assign from inside renderPlot using `<<-`. See http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html